# String separated by # and ｜ to json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, text

I am sorry if this is a newbie question, I am recently started to work with Javascript.

I've got a string that looks like this:

```
myString = "#101|Maria|Smith|Teacher|26000|Football #102|Albert|Sullivan|Pianist|85000|Swimming"
```

My desired outcome would be a json like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "101"
        "Name": "Maria",
        "LastName": "Smith"
        "Job": "Teacher",
        "Salary": "26000",
        "FavSport": "Football"
    },
    {
        "id": "102"
        "Name": "Albert",
        "LastName": "Sullivan"
        "Job": "Pianist",
        "Salary": "85000",
        "FavSport": "Swimming"
    }
]
```

I have tried using myString.split('#') but it returns an array that is still separated by vertical bars and that I am not able to separate. Any ideas are highly appreciated

Comment: I guess you have done something like `res = myString.split('#')`. Then you could use a for loop or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the strings in the array, split them and convert them to objects. Did you try these, and if yes where did you get stuck?

Comment: And if you have control over the data format, try to change it to a common one (JSON, XML, etc). The way it is currently it is hard to parse and for example if a job contains `#` or `|` it could break

Comment: @A_A not to talk about spaces...

Comment: what about having separators as values?

Comment: split on `#`, loop over that array and split again on `|`and do the mapping to the object. This is the basics of how CSV works, plenty of examples on that out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Split** by space `" "` to get first your groups
Then, **split** by pipe `"|"` to get an array of values
Then `.map()` your array to a new Array of objects

```js
const myString = "#101|Maria|Smith|Teacher|26000|Football #102|Albert|Sullivan|Pianist|85000|Swimming";

const groups = myString.split(" ");

const result = groups.map((groupString) => {
  const [id, Name, LastName, Job, Salary, FavSport] = groupString.split("|");
  return {id: id.replace("#", ""), Name, LastName, Job, Salary, FavSport};
});

console.log(result)
```

Then, to convert it to a JSON String use:

```js
const json = JSON.stringify(result);
```

---

PS: Anyways, I would highly discourage you from using that input string format

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I know it's not ideal but is what the API returns and I wanted to adapt it to json format for datatables. This work wonders, many thanks!!